# Loop for resetando a variável de controle em c++ Qt Creator

Tags: c++, loop, for, qt

Boa noite.
Estou fazendo um programa que converte bases numéricas em Qt Creator usando C++, e a função que converte de qualquer base para a decimal, tem um loop for:

```
int toDeci(QString str, int base)
{
    int len = str.size();
    int num = 0;  // Initialize result
    int valor;
    int i = 0;
    int potencia;

    for (i = 0; i < len; i++)
    {
        qDebug() << "Valor de i no inicio: " << i;
        if (val(str.at(i)) >= base)
        {
            return -1;
        }
        else
        {
            qDebug() << "Inicio do loop";
            qDebug() << "Valor de i: " << i;

            valor = val(str.at(i));
            qDebug() << "Valor do caractere: " << valor;
            qDebug() << "Valor de len " << len;
            potencia = qPow(base, len-1);
            qDebug() << "Valor da potencia: " << potencia;
            num += val(str.at(i)) * qPow(base, len-1);
            qDebug() << "Valor de num: " << num;
            len--;
            qDebug() << "Fim do loop";
            qDebug() << "Valor de i no inicio: " << i;
        }
    }
    return num;
}
```

O problema é que o loop está sendo executado duas vezes. Coloquei esses qDebug() para mostrar os valores das variáveis, e parece que a variável de controle i é reiniciada uma vez, fazendo o loop rodar duas vezes, mesmo com len valendo 1.
No debug sai isso:

```
Valor de i no inicio:  0

Inicio do loop

Valor de i:  0

Valor do caractere:  1

Valor de len  1

Valor da potencia:  1

Valor de num:  1

Fim do loop

Valor de i no final:  1

Valor de i no inicio:  0

Inicio do loop

Valor de i:  0

Valor do caractere:  1

Valor de len  1

Valor da potencia:  1

Valor de num:  1

Fim do loop

Valor de i no final:  1
```

Como fazer o loop executar apenas uma vez? Mudar o valor inicial de i faz o loop não executar.

Answer (score 0):

Implementei a função val e colei seu código em um projeto Qt de console, mas não consegui reproduzir o mesmo problema.

```
#include <qdebug.h>
#include <qmath.h>

int val(QChar c) {
    return c.digitValue();
}
int toDeci(QString str, int base)
{
    int len = str.size();
    int num = 0;  // Initialize result
    int valor;
    int i = 0;
    int potencia;

    for (i = 0; i < len; i++)
    {
        qDebug() << "Valor de i no inicio: " << i;
        if (val(str.at(i)) >= base)
        {
            return -1;
        }
        else
        {
            qDebug() << "Inicio do loop";
            qDebug() << "Valor de i: " << i;

            valor = val(str.at(i));
            qDebug() << "Valor do caractere: " << valor;
            qDebug() << "Valor de len " << len;
            potencia = qPow(base, len-1);
            qDebug() << "Valor da potencia: " << potencia;
            num += val(str.at(i)) * qPow(base, len-1);
            qDebug() << "Valor de num: " << num;
            len--;
            qDebug() << "Fim do loop";
            qDebug() << "Valor de i no inicio: " << i;
        }
    }
    return num;
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    qDebug() << "Resultado: " << toDeci("20", 16);
    return 0;
}
```

Saída:

```
Valor de i no inicio:  0
Inicio do loop
Valor de i:  0
Valor do caractere:  2
Valor de len  2
Valor da potencia:  16
Valor de num:  32
Fim do loop
Valor de i no inicio:  0
Resultado:  32
```

Não tenho resposta definitiva, mas acredito que no seu caso tenha a ver com o fato de que em C++ nem sempre um loop for é garantido de ser executado em ordem sequencial. Existe a possibilidade do seu compilador ter otimizado as operações e executado o loop for assumindo que len era um valor x constante, qdo na verdade deveria ser x variável. Compilei o programa no kit Qt 5.14.0 Desktop MinGW em Debug e Release, mas como não tenho outros kits disponíveis não posso falar isso com certeza.
Minha sugestão é trocar o loop for por um while, para garantir a ordem de execução das instruções.

```
    while(i < len)
    {
        valor = str.at(i).digitValue();
        potencia = qPow(base, len-1);

        if (valor >= base)
            return -1;
        else
            num += valor * potencia;

        len--;
        i++;
    }
```